# rsync functionality wanted - but i need symlinks, not copies

Tags: linux, unix, rsync, symbolic-link

Is there a way to perform what   rsync does (compiles many directories into a single directory) - But instead of copying files/sub-directories I need it to create a directory with symlinks that point to the original files/sub-directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous.

```
cp -l "$SRCDIR"/* "$DESTDIR"

find "$SRCDIR" -mindepth 1 \( -type d -printf 'mkdir "$DESTDIR/%P"\n' \) -o \
  \( -printf 'cp -l "%p" "$DESTDIR/%P"\n' \) | DESTDIR="$DESTDIR" bash
```

The first creates symlinks to the various items directly in `$SRCDIR`. The second recreates the directory structure and creates symlinks to the non-directories.

Comment: note also that `cp -l` makes hard links, whereas `cp -s` makes symlinks.  If the tree is large and the 2nd option ends up being at all slow, it could also be accomplished with something along the lines of: `for i in $(cd srcdir; find . -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '"%p" '); do mkdir -p "dstdir/${i}"; cp -l $(find "srcdir/${i}" -maxdepth 1 -not -type d -printf '"%p" ') "dstdir/${i}"`.

Comment: Two things I left out: 1) `cp -s` is only able to do relative symlinks if copying into the same directory, and 2) the `cp` command in my modification requires an `eval`.